# AngujarJS async "authenticated" check

Tags: http, angularjs

I want to show/hide elements in my HTML depending on whether user is authenticated. My HTML is static, checking is done by Ajax `GET /check` when there's a cookie called `session`. The following works:

HTML:

```
<div class="ng-cloak" ng-show="loggedIn()">Foo</div>
<div class="ng-cloak" ng-hide="loggedIn()">Bar</div>
```

CoffeeScript:

```
angular.module('app', ['ngCookies']).run ($cookies, $http, $rootScope) ->
    if $cookies.session
        $http.get('/check').success (data) -> $rootScope.user = data

    $rootScope.loggedIn = ->
        if $rootScope.user then true else false
```

The problem is, when user is authenticated (`user` is not null thus `loggedIn()` is true), there's a short period where Bar is still shown, because the script is still waiting for `GET /check` to return (so `user` is still null thus `loggedIn()` is false). How do I fix this?

**UPDATE:** Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/dexrN/1/ (removed `$cookies` and replaced `$http` with `$timeout`)

Comment: Can you set up a fiddle or a plunk? I'm not sure why it would show both, but I have a feeling we're missing something. (Side note, you don't need the loggedIn() function, you could just use ng-show="user" or ng-hide="user", but it's not a big deal.)

Comment: @blesh I have updated the question with fiddle.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@mark-rajcok is correct, but too verbose for my case. Here's the solution I end up using, basically introducing `loggedOut()`:

```
<div class="ng-cloak" ng-show="loggedIn()">Foo</div>
<div class="ng-cloak" ng-show="loggedOut()">Bar</div>
```

CoffeeScript:

```
angular.module('app', ['ngCookies']).run ($cookies, $http, $rootScope) ->
    if $cookies.session
        $http.get('/check')
            .success (data) ->
                $rootScope.user = data
            .error -> 
                $rootScope.user = {}
                delete $cookies.session
    else
        $rootScope.user = {}

    $rootScope.loggedIn = -> $rootScope.user and $rootScope.user.username
    $rootScope.loggedOut = -> $rootScope.user and not $rootScope.user.username
```

Answer (score 1):

Since you need three states (not two), use [ng-switch](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.directive%3angSwitch) (instead of ng-hide/ng-show) to switch on three states:  unknown, logged in, not logged in.  You may need to use another $scope property for this.